# box2d many static object

Tags: box2d, cocos2d-x, box2d-iphone

I'm on stage a lot of static objects - obstacles. I add them as follows:

```
 b2BodyDef groundBodyDef;
                    groundBodyDef.position.Set(i/PTM_RATIO, j/PTM_RATIO);

                    b2Body *groundBody = world->CreateBody(&groundBodyDef);
                    b2PolygonShape groundEdge;
                    b2FixtureDef boxShapeDef;
                    boxShapeDef.shape = &groundEdge;

                    groundEdge.SetAsBox(64/PTM_RATIO, 64/PTM_RATIO);
                    groundBody->CreateFixture(&boxShapeDef);
```

And it turns out that such objects around 2000 and eventually begins to slow down the application .. 
How can I add a simple square girlfriend static objects just for the Coliseum?

Comment: You should probably use b2EdgeChain shapes to create the outline of your world. And use only one body but with multiple shapes (fixtures) may also help with performance.

Comment: So ... a little not understand. Here I need to make a square with the origin at (20, 20) and the end (40.40) and the second square with the origin at (100,100) and the end (120,120). how do I do? And there will be many squares

Answer (score 0):

You should remove or reuse bodies that leave the screen. For example, in a side scrolling game, when an obstacle leaves throught he left screen edge it is most likely to not return, so it is safe to either remove it (so that box2d won't take it into account when checking collision, and also you win;t have to take them into account in your moethods) or reuse them - you could change the position of such body, so that it will be again on the right.

Either way, you shouldn't create a lot of bodies, as this is a sure and fast way to hog down your performance.

Comment: But what do I do if all these bodies need me always, whether they are in a region of the screen or not. 
I need these bodies simply to limit the movement may have a different method such as add static body?

Comment: Could you edit your original question with more details, preferably a sketch of what you want to achieve and why do you need so many bodies?